# why on text change combobox selection change

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, textbox

Sorry i think may be not clear the question :

The problem is I have a Windows Form where I fill a `ComboBox` from my code and set the `SelectedIndex` to **1** . My problem is that when I write something all `ComboBox`'s `SelectedIndex` automatically changes to **0**.

First picture shows when I still haven't filled in any value. The second one, is when I write something in the `TextBox`.

[image: Withoutchange]
[image]

I don't have a `TextChanged` event. I would also make clear that I am using `BindingSource` for this form.

My code for the `ComboBox` is like this:

```
  private void FillNationality()
    {   

        var items = new BindingList<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

        items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("E", "Expatriate"));
        items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("R", "Resident"));
        items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Z", "Zambian"));

        nationalityComboBox.DataSource = items;
        nationalityComboBox.ValueMember = "Key";
        nationalityComboBox.DisplayMember = "Value";
        nationalityComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

Can you please help me about this problem?

Comment: maybe there's a code on your `Emp Code` textbox's `TextChanged` event?

Comment: @GianAcuna No there is nothing i write anytype of code on text change

Comment: Hmm are all the controls bound to a source? If so, I guess changing the textbox's content causes a new record event that's why all the other controls are reset.

Comment: yes  i think problem is happening because of that . how can i resolve that

Comment: @GianAcuna yes i use `bindingsource` for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **ComboBox** is being reset as it is **bounded to TextBox**,and as the Text in TextBox changes bounded controls are updated.I am not sure if my answer will prevent the issue,but give it a try.In the **TextChanged** event of your **TextBox** add the following code;

```
int value=1;//Set this value equal to index that you want to select.

private void Textbox_TextChangedEvent(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
   Combobox.SelectedIndex=value;//Change Combobox to you control's name.
}
```

I know it looks crazy,'selecting a value in combobox everytime a character is typed in TextBox'.But what's the loss in trying?